Trying to pass a string from one file to another, but failing

#include <string.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    
    FILE *Arquivo, *Arquivo2;
    char SerPassado[100], str[100];
    
    // Open Archive.txt for writing
    Arquivo = fopen("Archive.txt", "w");
    if (Arquivo == NULL) {
        perror("Error ao abrir Archive.txt para escrita");
        return 1;
    }
    
    // Get strings from user and write them to Archive.txt
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Enter a string: ");
        if (fgets(SerPassado, sizeof(SerPassado), stdin) == NULL) {
            perror("Error ao ler entrada");
            fclose(Arquivo);
            return 1;
        }
        fputs(SerPassado, Arquivo);
    }
    
    fflush(Arquivo);
    
    fclose(Arquivo);
    
    // Open Archive.txt for reading and Archive2.txt for writing
    Arquivo = fopen("Archive.txt", "r");
    Arquivo2 = fopen("Archive2.txt", "w");
    if (Arquivo == NULL || Arquivo2 == NULL) {
        perror("Error ao abrir arquivo");
        return 1;
    }
    
    // Copy content from Archive.txt to Archive2.txt
    while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), Arquivo)) {
        fputs(str, Arquivo2);
    }
    
    fclose(Arquivo);
    fclose(Arquivo2);
    
    // Reopen Archive2.txt for reading and print its content
    Arquivo2 = fopen("Archive2.txt", "r");
    if (Arquivo2 == NULL) {
        perror("Erro ao abrir Archive2.txt para leitura");
        return 1;
    }
    
    while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), Arquivo2)) {
        printf("%s", str);
    }
    
    fclose(Arquivo2);
    return 0;
    
}

Always, when I run this code, the "Arquivo2" does not receive the string it should receive. Help! This one is already "corrected" by GPT, but yet it does not work. After I write 5 strings to the first file, those 5 strings will not be passed next to the second file.

Please explain what was in your origin file and what ended up being stored in the destination file.

As noted, I did a quick edit of your first line of code, breaking out each "#include" statement onto a separate line to allow the code to compile.  After that, testing the code with strings that were less than 100 characters seemed to produce the desired results with both files containing the entered text.  We would need to see the alleged entered string data to attempt to replicate the problem.

It works for me: https://onlinegdb.com/qIVBqJTUu

Have you checked what's in Archive.txt after the program runs?  Is there anything in Archive2.txt after the program runs?  You could check the currently unchecked uses of fputs() and printf().  That probably won't help, but when you're encountering the inexplicable, ruling out errors is a good idea.  You could even check fflush() and fclose(), though it's unlikely that'll help either.

Your code appears to work fine. Please [edit] and show your input, the output and the content of both Archive.txt and Archive2.txt. Are you sure the program you run is the program you compiled?
